# How to find and click the "Like" button on Facebook page using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to automate the process of liking pages on Facebook. I've got a list of each page's link and I want to open and like them one by one.
I think the Like button doesn't have any id or name, but it is in a span class.

```
<span class="x1lliihq x6ikm8r x10wlt62 x1n2onr6 xlyipyv xuxw1ft">Like</span>
```

I used this code to find and click on the "Like" button.

```
def likePages(links, driver):
    for link in links:
        driver.get(link)
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Like').click()
```

And I get the following error when I run the function:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *classname* attribute values like *`x1lliihq`*, *`x6ikm8r`*, etc, are dynamically generated and is bound to chage sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

Moreover the the element is a `<span>` tag so you can't use *`By.LINK_TEXT`*

---

### Solution

To click on the element <kbd>Like</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and *`text()`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Like']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`contains()`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'Like')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions on [***NoSuchElementException***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Link_Text` locator as **Like** is not a hyperlink. Use XPath instead, see below:

XPath : `//span[contains(text(),"Like")]`

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),"Like")]').click()`